# LDAP HTTP Authentication with Symfony 2.8 and 3.1

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, ldap

I have taken a look at this documentation, but it has not helped me: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/ldap.html

I have a problem that I can't login with any users.

Log file old:

```
[2016-07-06 16:56:11] request.INFO: Matched route "company_threesoccer_default_soccerfacebook". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"company\\ThreeSoccerBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::soccerFacebookAction","_route":"company_threesoccer_default_soccerfacebook"},"request_uri":"http://iadevelopment.instance/app_dev.php/three/soccer/facebook"} []
[2016-07-06 16:56:11] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient class is deprecated since version 3.1 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the Ldap class directly instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php","line":169,"args":["/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/ldap/LdapClient.php"],"function":"require_once"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\DebugClassLoader","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":1592,"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3639,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":2133,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":314,"function":"getSecurity_Firewall_Map_Context_MainService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2944,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2586,"function":"getListeners","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\Security\\FirewallMap","type":"->"},{"function":"onKernelRequest","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php","line":61,"function":"call_user_func"},{"function":"__invoke","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1858,"function":"call_user_func"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/app/cache/dev/classes.php","line":1773,"function":"doDispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php","line":140,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":125,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":64,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php","line":69,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php","line":193,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/web/app_dev.php","line":30,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"}]} []
[2016-07-06 16:56:11] security.INFO: Basic authentication Authorization header found for user. {"username":"rov"} []
[2016-07-06 16:56:11] security.INFO: Basic authentication failed for user. {"username":"rov","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:73, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\UsernameNotFoundException(code: 0): Username \"rov\" does not exist. at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/InMemoryUserProvider.php:109)"} []
```

**Log file updated:**

```
[2016-07-07 15:33:13] request.INFO: Matched route "{route}". {"route":"homepage","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::testAction","_route":"homepage"},"request_uri":"http://ldap.test/app_dev.php/test","method":"GET"} []
[2016-07-07 15:33:13] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient class is deprecated since version 3.1 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the Ldap class directly instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php","line":142,"args":["/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/LdapClient.php"],"function":"require_once"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\DebugClassLoader","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":1659,"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":275,"function":"getLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3549,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":275,"function":"getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_MyLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3477,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":275,"function":"getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":2164,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":275,"function":"getSecurity_Firewall_Map_Context_MainService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/classes.php","line":3353,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/classes.php","line":3019,"function":"getListeners","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\Security\\FirewallMap","type":"->"},{"function":"onKernelRequest","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php","line":61,"function":"call_user_func"},{"function":"__invoke","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2144,"function":"call_user_func"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2059,"function":"doDispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php","line":136,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":129,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":68,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php","line":177,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/web/app_dev.php","line":30,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"}]} []
[2016-07-07 15:33:13] security.INFO: An AuthenticationException was thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): A Token was not found in the TokenStorage. at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:53)"} []
[2016-07-07 15:33:13] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []
[2016-07-07 15:33:20] request.INFO: Matched route "{route}". {"route":"homepage","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::testAction","_route":"homepage"},"request_uri":"http://ldap.test/app_dev.php/test","method":"GET"} []
[2016-07-07 15:33:20] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient class is deprecated since version 3.1 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the Ldap class directly instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/LdapClient.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php","line":142,"args":["/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/LdapClient.php"],"function":"require_once"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\DebugClassLoader","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":1659,"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":275,"function":"getLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3549,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":275,"function":"getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_MyLdapService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":3477,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":275,"function":"getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":2164,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php","line":275,"function":"getSecurity_Firewall_Map_Context_MainService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/classes.php","line":3353,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/classes.php","line":3019,"function":"getListeners","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\Security\\FirewallMap","type":"->"},{"function":"onKernelRequest","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php","line":61,"function":"call_user_func"},{"function":"__invoke","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2144,"function":"call_user_func"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/classes.php","line":2059,"function":"doDispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php","line":136,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":129,"function":"dispatch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":68,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php","line":177,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/web/app_dev.php","line":30,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"}]} []
[2016-07-07 15:33:20] security.INFO: Basic authentication Authorization header found for user. {"username":"rov"} []
[2016-07-07 15:33:20] php.DEBUG: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials {"type":2,"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/Adapter/ExtLdap/Connection.php","line":53,"level":28928} []
[2016-07-07 15:33:20] security.INFO: Basic authentication failed for user. {"username":"rov","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:73, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\UsernameNotFoundException(code: 0): User \"rov\" not found. at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/LdapUserProvider.php:69, Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\Exception\\ConnectionException(code: 0): Invalid credentials at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/Adapter/ExtLdap/Connection.php:54)"} []
```

`security.yml` code old:

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: ldap
            base_dn: DC=company,DC=de
            search_dn: "cn=Users, DC=company,DC=de"
            search_password: MyBestPasswordEver
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: sAMAccountName
firewalls:
    main:
        http_basic_ldap:
            service: ldap
            dn_string: 'sAMAccountName={username},DC=company,DC=de'
```

**`security.yml` code updated:**

```
providers:
#   in_memory:
#        memory: ~
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: ldap
            base_dn: DC=company,DC=de
            search_dn: "cn=symfony, DC=company,DC=de"  # symfony is a user in ldap
            search_password: MyBestPasswordEver
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: sAMAccountName

firewalls:
   main:
        http_basic_ldap:
            provider: my_ldap
            service: ldap
            dn_string: "{username}"
  #          dn_string: "sAMAccountname={username},DC=company,DC=de, cn=Users"
```

`services.yml` code old:

```
services:
    ldap:
        class: 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient'
        arguments:
            - ldaps://adc1.company.de   # host
            - 389                       # port
            - 3                         # version
            - true                      # SSL
            - false                     # TLS
```

**`services.yml`code updated:**

```
services:
  ldap:
    class: 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient'
    arguments:
        - adc1.company.de   # host
#            - 636                           # port, without ssl 389, with 636
#            - 2                             # version
#            - true                          # SSL
#            - false                         # TLS
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something that I have missed?

I have also installed

```
 "symfony/ldap": "^3.1"
```

Best regards

Comment: If this is solved, please add and accept an answer below, in the answer space. If any of your question edits are the solution and not additional items to the question, please roll them back and summarise them in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change your `dn_string` to just `{username}`. You'll also went to set it to your LDAP user provider:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        http_basic_ldap:
            provider: my_ldap 
            service: ldap
            dn_string: "{username}"
```

That is actually the default value for `dn_string`, so technically you could leave it out altogether.

**Edit:**

Also, your `search_dn: "cn=Users, DC=company,DC=de"` needs to be the DN of a user. Right now it's pointing at the User's container. It should be the full DN of a user that performs the LDAP query needed to search for the user.

Comment: Thx, but nothing had changed.

Comment: What do your logs say now? This part is telling you that it's currently looking in the in_memory user provider instead of LDAP: `Username \"rov\" does not exist. at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IA_Development_Instance/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/InMemoryUserProvider.php:109)"}`. I also updated my answer as your `search_dn` value is a container, but it needs to be a user.

Comment: I have commented out the in_memory user provider and edited the DN.
But its the same as before. I had try symfony 3.1 too.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Now your issue really is with the LDAP user provider. `ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials {"type":2,"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ldapTest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/Adapter/ExtLdap/Connection.php","line":53,"level":28928} []`. That looks to be the LDAP User Provider trying to bind the connection before the search. I would change the your LDAP service arguments back to how they were, but also disable SSL for the purpose of testing. So `- false         # SSL`

Comment: Now i have a connection with my symfony user.
The error was that i forgot to write the domain from out company to the search_dn.
But now when i want to authenticate another User, i've got this error message:

    `Could not complete search with dn "DC=company,DC=de", query "(sAMAccountname=company\5crov)" and filters "*"`

The ldap controller puts a 5c after a backslash.
sAMAccountname is configured in the `security.yml` with the uid_key:
                `uid_key: sAMAccountname`
Is the a possibility to change it to:
uid_key: sAMAccountname=Company/{username} ?

Comment: When i write:
`uid_key: sAMAccountname=Company\ `
in the `security.yml` then he puts a `=` after the uid_key string.

Comment: AH now i have it :)
The last tweak was the `base_dn: `cn=Users`,DC=company,DC=de` in the `security.yml`->providers->myldap

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: For info. Works only in symfony 3.1, not in 2.8